# Killing neighbours dog

Tags: karma, killing, animals

Hi may I know what is the karma of killing a dog please?

My neighbours dog starts barking from 5am daily and I don't get enough sleep. I am so tired at work and cannot focus. I've tried soundproofing my walls and using ear plugs  but they don't work I can still hear the barking.

I've spoken to the neighbour but he tells me that he is a human and he can't ask ask his dog to keep quiet (whatever that means).

I am at my wits end, I am so tired, I never get enough rest. Can I kill the dog? May I know what is the karma for killing a dog?

Comment: Where I live, I can report barking dogs to the local council, who have the power to remove the dog.

Comment: Please don't kill. Remember the first precept  **I shouldn't kill even a mosquito it bite me**   And you should know when Devdatta had injured a swan with bow  then in the council one said  **"A life certainly must belong to him who tries to save it; a life cannot belong to one who is only trying to destroy it. The wounded bird by right belongs to the one who saved its life. Let the swan be given to Siddhattha."**  So please.

Answer (score 2):

The karmic result for killing a dog is:

1. Possible retaliation by your neighbor.
2. Possible legal action by neighbor and government.
3. Possible regret & guilty conscience in your heart.
4. Getting scored negative on [Buddhism Stack Exchange](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions).
5. Not woken up at 5 am; getting an improved night's sleep; more focus & energy at work.
6. Woken up at 4 am by a new different dog.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [dog silencer product](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpSbhb3VkX0)? Killing the Dog or contemplating to kill is bad Karma for you.

Answer (score 0):

If an individual hates and intentionally kills a life, that individual breaks the first precept.

Because no one likes death.

If you kill that dog, you commit a breach of the precept.

So, please consider a better solution